# MarkLogic 8: Cannot load a XML document to MarkLogic database using cURL

Tags: xml, database, marklogic, marklogic-8

I'm practicing to load a simple XML document (I name it one.xml) with content:

```
<one>
 <child>The noble Brutus has told Caesar was ambitious</child>
</one>
```

to MarkLogic DB.

I run curl tool (Windows cmd) at one.xml's directory and type the following command line:

```
   curl --anyauth --user user:password -x put  -d@"./one.xml" ^
   -h "Content-type: application/xml" ^
   "http://localhost:8000/LATEST/documents?uri=/xml/one.xml"
```

So if the request succeeds, the service returns status 201 (Document Created).
But nothing happened. Instead, I received the results of the *"curl --help"* command.

I folllow the instructions of MarkLogic website. Link: https://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/guide/rest-dev/intro#id_97899

Scroll down to the **Getting Started with the MarkLogic REST API** article. I am stuck at *Load Documents Into the Database*

P/S: The curl command line in the MarkLogic website use Unix syntax, so I changed it to Windows syntax following this link https://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/guide/rest-dev/intro#id_75672

I think this is a problem. Please help me

Answer (score 2):

You mistyped the [`-X` parameter](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-X), it must be upper-case X. Lower-case [x parameter](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-x) is used for something else..

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it still doesn't work. I don't know if there are any mistake left